# Configure pfSense from LAN to WAN to LAN

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan, pfsense

I have a simple website running accessible from internet using port forwarding for 80 and 443.

Now I noticed that I cannot access this website myself. The website is default only available for people on the internet.

Of course I can use the DNS resolver to resolve the domain name to local LAN IP address.

The thing is that the software that I am using to run the website performs a DNS lookup, resolves it to the public IP and fails to connect to it's own service.

How do I configure pfSense to allow this type of traffic?

I think I need some extra inbound rule?

Comment: The search keywords for this are "NAT hairpin" or "NAT loopback". (I _think_ pfSense used to have a built-in checkbox for it.)

Comment: *Of course I can use the DNS resolver to resolve the domain name to local LAN IP address.* You *need* to do that. The traffic for that server never reaches the internet. All lookups for that domain should resolve to a local IP, not a public IP.  It's called split dns